# Perl Regex negation for multiple words

Tags: regex, perl

I need to exclude some URLs for a jMeter test:

dont exclude:

```
http://foo/bar/is/valid/with/this
http://foo/bar/is/also/valid/with/that
```

exclude:

```
http://foo/bar/is/not/valid/with/?=action
http://foo/bar/is/not/valid/with/?=action
http://foo/bar/is/not/valid/with/specialword
```

Please help me?

My following Regex isnt working:

```
foo/(\?=|\?action|\?form_action|specialword).*
```

Comment: Do you mean `http://foo/bar/is/not/valid/with/?=action` or just `http://foo/bar/is/not/valid/with/action`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: `/` is the general delimiter so escape it with `\/` or alter the delimiter.
Second Problem: It will match only `foo/action` and so on, you need to include a wildcard before the brackets: `foo\/.*(\?=|\?action|\?form_action|specialword).*`

So:

```
/foo\/.*(\?=|\?action|\?form_action|specialword).*/
```

Next problem is that this will match the opposite: Your excludes. You can either finetune your regex to do the inverse OR you can handle this in your language (i.e. if there is no match, do this and that).

Always pay attention to special characters in regex. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) also.

Comment: `/` *isn't* a special character in regular expressions - it is simply the default delimiter for them in Perl. If you use a different delimiter (together with the `m` opertaor which is implicit if you use slashes) there is no problem with embedded slashes. It is also misleading to add the `/g` modifier, which is almost certainly superfluous.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the language regex was used in, I tested my regex in JavaScript. Correct, it is not a special char, jast a delimiter used generally. I will alter my solution to include this.

Comment: Hey, since it is a regex for jMeter I cant handle this in "my language". jMeter is using Perl regex to exclude URL's and therefore I need a one line statement. Ive been trying to do it like this:                 
`ws\/.*(?!webform|?!\?=|?!\?action|?!\?form_action|?!specialword).*` Well, jMeter doesnt accept this one :(!

Comment: I am sorry, this goes beyond my regex knowledge. I would be interested to hear someone elses solution and you should probably accept that solution then.

Answer (score 1):

There are countless ways to shoot yourself in the foot with regular expressions. You could write some kind of "parser" using  /g and /c in a loop, but why bother? It seems like you are already having trouble with the current regular expression.

Break the problem down into smaller parts and everything will be less complicated. You could write yourself some kind of *filter* for `grep` like:

```
sub filter {
    my $u = shift;
    my $uri = URI->new($u);
    return undef if $uri->query;
    return undef if grep { $_ eq 'specialword' } $uri->path_segments;
    return $u;
}

say for grep {filter $_} @urls;
```

I wouldn't cling that hard to a regular expression, especially if others have to read the code too...

Comment: You're totally right about this. But I have to find a one line statement for jMeter, since I only got this one line to filter URL's from getting randomly called.. Thanks for your advice, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Change the regex delimiter to something other than '/' so you don't have to escape it in your matches.  You might do:

```
m{//foo/.+(?:\?=action|\?form_action|specialword)$};
```

The ?: denotes grouping-only.

Using this, you could say:

```
print unless m{//foo/.+(?:\?=action|\?form_action|specialword)$};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your alternation is wrong. `foo/(\?=|\?action|\?form_action|specialword)` matches any of

- `foo/?=`
- `foo/?action`
- `foo/?form_action`
- `foo/?specialword`

so you need instead

```
m{foo/.*(?:\?=action|\?=form_action|specialword)}
```

The `.*` is necessary to account for the possible `bar/is/valid/with/this` after `/foo/`.

Note that I have changed your `( .. )` to the non-capturing `(?: .. )` and I have used braces for the regex delimiter to avoid having to escape the slashes in the expression.

Finally, you need to write either

```
unless ($url =~ m{/foo/.*(?:\?=action|\?=form_action|specialword)}) { ... }
```

or

```
if ($url !~ m{/foo/.*(?:\?=action|\?=form_action|specialword)}) { ... }
```

since the regex matches URLs that are to be *discarded*.

Comment: Hey, i can't use Perl to negate this regex. jMeter filters URL's by using Perls regex so I can actually tell jMeter to randomly click all available paths behind `/foo/` but therefore I need to exclude stuff like ?=action, since this would delete stuff from my webapplication database etc... thanks for your help !